# How to change the input type in a form based on an Enum select list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How would you change the input type to a value such as text, range, or text area based on the selected enum before pressing the submit button? This is so that when a user changes the selected element, they will have a different input type to select a quantity. Here is what I have currently

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome @Model.UnitOne</h1>
</div>

<form method="post" asp-page="Index">
    <!--UNIT TYPE-->
    <select asp-items="@(Html.GetEnumSelectList<model.UnitTypes>())" asp-for="UnitType"></select>
    <!--UNIT ONE-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="@Model.UnitOneSelected" id="unitOne"/>
    </div>
    <select asp-items="@(Html.GetEnumSelectList<model.UnitTypes>())" asp-for="UnitType" onchange="@Model.UnitOneSelected"></select>
    <!--UNIT TWO-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="@Model.UnitTwoSelected" id="unitTwo"/>
    </div>
    <select asp-items="@(Html.GetEnumSelectList<model.UnitTypes>())" asp-for="UnitType" onchange="@Model.UnitTwoSelected"></select>
    <!--SUBMIT BUTTON-->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Use JavaScript to detect a change in the selected value and modify the corresponding field control accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple demo about how to change the type by dropdown select:

Model:

```
namespace RazorPagesProj.Models
{        
    public enum UnitTypes
    {
        text,
        password,
        date,
        number
    }
}
```

Razor Page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@using RazorPagesProj.Models;


<form method="post" asp-page="Index">
    <!--UNIT TYPE-->
    <select asp-items="@(Html.GetEnumSelectList<UnitTypes>())" asp-for="UnitType"></select>
    <!--UNIT ONE-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="unitOne"/>
    </div>
    <select asp-items="@(Html.GetEnumSelectList<UnitTypes>())" asp-for="UnitType" onchange="ChangeUnitOne(this)"></select>
    <!--UNIT TWO-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="unitTwo" />
    </div>
    <select asp-items="@(Html.GetEnumSelectList<UnitTypes>())" asp-for="UnitType" onchange="ChangeUnitTwo(this)"></select>
    <!--SUBMIT BUTTON-->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function ChangeUnitOne(ele) {
            var selected = $(ele).find("option:selected").text();
            $("#unitOne").attr('type', selected);
        }
        function ChangeUnitTwo(ele) {
            var selected = $(ele).find("option:selected").text();
            $("#unitTwo").attr('type', selected);
        }
    </script>      
}
```

PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public UnitTypes UnitTypes { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string UnitType { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }

    //more code...
}
```